# Database Designing Suggestion For Products and Featured Product

Tags: database, database-design

I will be creating an Application that will be showing the Products in a Matrix 3*8.

The top row is reserved for the Featured Products. The featured Product may be sometimes 0 or sometimes upto 3.

The featured product has lot of additional details like 5-6 more additional columns compared to normal product.

I will be most probably binding all of them (Product and Featured Product to a databound control in ASP.NET)

**The problem is should i keep both the Product and Featured Product in same table or different table.**

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new table FeaturedProduct next to your Product table, with a foreign key to Product. The additional information is contained in this FeaturedProduct table. If a product exists in the FeaturedProduct table, then this means it's a featured product.

To build your UI you'll need to left outer join the two tables.